# C# Picturebox updating issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, camera

I'm writing a GUI that shows a video which is continously acquired from a camera. I've also developed a 'dll' for the camera in charge of acquiring frames. Every time a frame is acquired it generates an event.

When the main form loads, it registers to that event:

```
testCameraHandle = new CCameraHandle();
testCameraHandle.NewFrameAdded += testCameraHandle_NewFrameAdded;
```

In this way, every time a frame is acquired the GUI can update its picturebox:

```
delegate void NewFrameAddedDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);

private void testCameraHandle_NewFrameAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //"pbImage" is the name of the picturebox
    if (pbImage.InvokeRequired)
    {
        NewFrameAddedDelegate del = new NewFrameAddedDelegate(testCameraHandle_NewFrameAdded);
        pbImage.Invoke(del, sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        var oldImage = pbImage.Image;
        pbImage.Image = testCameraHandle.bitmap;
        if (oldImage != null)
            ((IDisposable)oldImage).Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the main form of this GUI I have also a `Windows.Forms.Timer` that runs every 5 ticks and takes 100ms to complete its cycle. This Timer is necessary to me and I can't remove or move it elsewhere. This structure isn't satisfactory because, even if the camera runs at 20 frames per seconds, the updating of the 'picturebox' is slow and jerky dued to the Timer. I can't figure out the way to have all of this working and a 'refresh rate' which is synchronized to the camera fps. Is there a solution to this problem? Or it is not possible having a good 'refresh rate' since the Timer is running? Thank you very much!

Edit:

I'm trying to use `System.Threading.Timer` but every time the camera starts grabbing then the timer stops cycling. I'm initializing the timer like this:

```
System.Threading.TimerCallback timerCallback = this.timerPLC_Tick;
System.Threading.Timer thTimer = new  System.Threading.Timer(timerPLC_Tick, null, 1000, 5000);
```

Comment: Refreshing is done by calling `Invalidate()`. You can save image (do not assign it to `PictureBox`) and call invalidate of control. In that control override `OnPaint` and simply draw this image.

Comment: *"In the main form of this GUI I have also a timer that runs every 5 ticks and takes 100ms to complete its cycle"* What kind of timer is it? A `Windows.Forms.Timer`? What does this timer do? UI interaction or just some long running logic?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure to have understood your suggestion. My problem is that, even though the camera works at 20fps, the picturebox in the GUI cannot catch all the frames since it is slower because of the 'Timer'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: yes it is a 'Windows.Forms.Timer'. It reads variables from a PLC and shows them to the user

Comment: Consider running the acquisition code in a `System.Threading.Timer` instead, the `Windows.Forms.Timer` will lock up the UI thread for 100ms (or however long it takes to complete) each time it runs. This means that your camera code will be blocked quite often.

Comment: What are you doing in this "every 5 ticks" Timer?  There may be another way to achieve your end goal...

Comment: @RonBeyer: I'm trying to use the "System.Threading.Timer" but as soon as the camera starts grabbing the timer stops its cycle.

Comment: @Enrico The way you've initialized it, the timer will wait 1 second before starting, then will call the `timerPLC_Tick` method every 5 seconds after that. Are you sure its stopped? Did you set a breakpoint inside the timer tick method?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes I've used a break point. It runs always until I click the button for grabbing frames. At that point the breakpoint is not crossed anymore

Comment: You will have to post the code where you start this timer, I have a feeling you are using a local method variable and it is going out of scope and getting garbage collected.

Comment: @RonBeyer you were right! I moved the declaration of the timer at global level and now is working fine! I'll try this on the final application..thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give update but I had to dedicate to another project until now. I've tryed using `System.Threading.Timer` and the refreshing of the picturebox is even worst than when I use `Windows.Forms.Timer`. Consider that the timer should run every 5ms. Cannot undestand the reason of this difference